# What am I doing wrong with this for loop in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm trying to implement the below code in a for loop, to avoid needing to have every XOR term written out separately.

```
unsigned int check_0 = P0^en[2]^en[4]^en[6]^en[8]^en[10]^en[12]^en[14]^en[16]^en[18]^en[20]^en[22]^en[24]^en[26]^en[28]^en[30];
```

This is what I've written, but it doesn't work. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
unsigned int check_0z = P0;
unsigned int check_0 = 0;

 int i = 2;
  for (i = 2; i > 30; i += 2){
    check_0 = check_0z^en[i];
    check_0z = check_0;
  }
```

Comment: `for (i = 2; i > 30; i += 2){` You need less than/equal there.

Comment: `for (i = 2; i > 30; i += 2){` -> `for (i = 2; i <= 30; i += 2){`

Comment: also no need for `check_0z`, just do `unsigned int check_0 = P0;` then the body of your loop `check_0 = check_0 ^ en[i];` or `check_0 ^= en[i];`

Comment: Thank you everyone, all sorted!